# How to force login before navigating to SObject record detail in experience site?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, experience-cloud

Within the experience site, an embedded Aura component is utilized, featuring a modal that includes an "OK" button. Upon clicking this button as a Guest user, the desired behavior is to seamlessly redirect the user to the corresponding record detail page. However, prior to accessing the record page, it is necessary for the user to complete the login or signup process.

Code that redirects Guest User to Record Page:

```js
redirectToRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": recordId
    });
    navEvent.fire();
}
```

Before redirecting to the record page it should ask user to login or signup but above code is not working as aspected.

I achieved required functionality by below code:

```js
redirectToRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    location.href = "/s/detail/" + recordId;
}
```

Above code redirecting to login/signup page and after login/signup user can see the record page. I don't think that above method is right approach to implement the needed functionality.

Could you please suggest me some workaround to achieve solve this issue?